# How to create a contract with private data accessible to a particular user?

Tags: private-key, encryption

I want to create a contract that stores encrypted data that is accessible only a selected user on the blockchain.

A ideal scenario would be to encrypt the data using the user's public key, such that the user can decrypt the data using their private key. Is there a public and private key equivalent on the Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a public and private key equivalent on the Ethereum blockchain?

It is possible to do public private key encryption with ethereum addresses: [How to encrypt a message with the public-key of an Ethereum address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-to-encrypt-a-message-with-the-public-key-of-an-ethereum-address)