# How to decrypt an ECIES encrypted message using a geth account and JSON-RPC protocol?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, private-key, keystore, encryption

A geth node is managing an Ethereum account, having the control over its private key at keystore folder. I guess to keep it safe, best practices are letting geth by its own perform all operations that require access to the private key. Well, the case is I need to decrypt a message that was encrypted using the public key of the geth account, in order to be only readable by this account. So, is there any geth function via JSON-RPC capable of decrypting a message using the private key of the account? Something like this:

```
ECIES.Decrypt(account, message);
```

The only other choice is left seems to be accessing directly to the keystore folder and decrypt the message using the private key there, but I don't feel comfortable doing so, it seems a quite insecure scheme, right?

Ref.:

[How to encrypt a message with the public-key of an Ethereum address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-to-encrypt-a-message-with-the-public-key-of-an-ethereum-address/3099)

Comment: I couldn't find any ECIES function at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC so I guess this (encryption/decryption) is not posiible to do using JSON-RPC protocol, right?

Comment: With Geth it isn't, with Parity it is – see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with Geth. However Parity does expose a module that does just that: see the [parity_decryptMessage()](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_decryptmessage) function.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty Juan. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it's what you were expecting.