# How to encrypt a message using only the public key from web3.eth.sign?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, encryption, public-key

I retrieve the public key of a users account using Web3 as follows:

```
 web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], web3.sha3('test'), function (err, signature) {
          var sigtest = signature
          const util = require('ethereumjs-util');
          const sig = util.fromRpcSig(sigtest);
          const publicKey = util.ecrecover(util.sha3('test'), sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);
      });
```

I then want to encrypt a message with this public key (without having a users private key) - [How to encrypt a message with the public-key of an Ethereum address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-to-encrypt-a-message-with-the-public-key-of-an-ethereum-address) gives an answer but in that example a private key is also given. How should this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this library it works perfectly.
https://github.com/LimelabsTech/eth-ecies

Comment: in that it appears its decrypted with a private key, I'd only have a public key to encrypt/decrypt

Comment: If you're doing symmetric encryption, why would you use a _public_ key to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`web3.eth.sign` is [deprecated](https://medium.com/metamask/the-new-secure-way-to-sign-data-in-your-browser-6af9dd2a1527) in `Metamask`

instead of `sign` use `sendAsync`:

```
  const signature = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
      method: 'personal_sign',
      params: [web3.utils.utf8ToHex(message), address],
      from: address,
    }, (err, response) => {
      if(err) return reject(err);
      resolve(response.result);
    });
  });
```

then use [eth-crypto](https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto)

to get address from signed message:

```
  const signer = EthCrypto.recover(
    signature,
    web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage(message)
  );
```

to get public key from signed message:

```
  const pubkey = EthCrypto.recoverPublicKey(
    signature,
    web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage(message)
  );
```

if you do recovering in browser just browserify eth-crypto:

```
  browserify node_modules/eth-crypto/dist/lib/browserify.index.js -o eth-crypto.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Public key cryptography relies on an asymmetric algorithm like RSA.

From a private key we get a public key to get pair keys=(priv,pub)

so encryption as a function is RSA: K x M -> C

where K,M,C is spaces of public keys, messages, ciphertexts respectively

and rsa(pub,m)=c is an instance specific to keys=(priv,pub)

We have a corresponding decryption function

dRSA: K' x C -> M

where Pr[drsa(priv,c) == m]==1

So the keys don't encrypt.. 'keyed' functions (algorithms like RSA) encrypt..